# PHP DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile, how to skip images and files?

Tags: php, domdocument

first of all, sorry about my english.

I'm working in HTML parser and i would skip the images and other downloadable stuff to be parsed.

I tried some variations and this is the last:

```
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTMLFile("http://exampledomain.com/images/img3.JPG");
    if($doc->hasChildNodes){break;}
```

After search a solution, i tried this:

```
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTMLFile("http://exampledomain.com/images/img3.JPG");
    var_dump($doc->childNodes->length);
    foreach($doc->childNodes as $child){
        var_dump($child->nodeName);
    }
```

Result:

```
    2
    html
    html
```

- question: how can an jpg file have 2 nodes html?
- question: how skip files (jpg, exe, doc, etc... non html files)

Comment: Why are you passing a `jpg` file to `loadHTMLFile` in the first place?

Comment: The very best thing would be to check the file's type before opening it for parsing, ideally by checking the downloaded file's `content-type` header... would require curl for downloading though

Comment: The reason of passing a jpg file to loadHTMLFile is because it comes from an automatic crawler, and finds all links (includes jpg, exe and other files linked un anchors). 

My second question should be "How skip files (jpg, exe, doc, etc... non html files) without checking extension, only with the DomDocument functions".

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you could do here is just check the filename for jpg, gif, png, js, whatever and not try to run `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile` on non-HTML files.  For some reason this function seems to try to load everything (probably because it's designed to handle invalid HTML) so you can't rely on the output of the function (`true` on success, `false` on failure).

Something like this might help:

```
if (false === preg_match('/^.*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i', $file_name)) {
   $doc = new DOMDocument();
   $doc->loadHTMLFile($file_name);
   // more code here
}
```

Comment: This solution does not help me because I can not check all possible file extensions other than html files, but thanks ;).

Comment: You can't check for a positive match for htm/html in the extension?

Comment: yes because, some other extension may be web documents (jps, asp, xhtml, php, etc... and customized extensions via .htaccess).